# Getting the value of text from a text object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML file which contains the following line:

```
<div><img src="img1.gif"><br>My Text</div>
```

I'm trying to select the phrase "My Text" using JavaScript so I can change it. I'm able to get the object that contains the text by using lastChild, but can't figure out how to get the value of the text itself.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
<div id="test"><img src="img1.gif"><br>My Text</div>

function getText( obj ) {
    return obj.textContent ? obj.textContent : obj.innerText;
}

function setText( obj, to ) {
    obj.textContent? obj.textContent = to : obj.innerText = to;
}

getText( document.getElementById('test') ) // 'My Text'
setText( document.getElementById('test').lastChild, 'bar' )
```

Note: innerText is for IE DOM, textContent is for the rest of the compliant DOM APIs such as Mozillas.

Comment: I forgot to specify `lastChild`, I just added it now.

Comment: @meder Don't think your tactical downvoting of everyone else's answer has gone unnoticed.

Comment: @Chris Ballance - Your answer is MS specific and will not work in modern browsers. Same with Scott's. The question did not include a jQuery tag nor can you set an ID on a text node, which is why I downvoted those.

Comment: @Corey - I didn't test this in IE but let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: @meder "my answer is better" is a flimsy excuse for Tactical Downvoting, but at least you owned up to it.

Answer (score 4):

you can access text content of the [object Text] by the "data" property.
this property is R/W so that you can use it to read text as well as to write it.

```
<div><img id="my_img_1" src="img1.gif">My Text</div>
<script>
    alert('my current text = ' + lastChild.data);
    lastChild.data = 'new text';
</script>
```

you can find more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_text.asp)

Answer (score 2):

if you have

```
<div><img src="img1.gif"><br><span>My Text</span></div>
```

then you can do

lastChild.innerHTML gets the value
and you can also do

```
lastChild.innerHTML="new text"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = the object you got
var theOldText = x.innerText
x.innerText = "new text"
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to put the value that you want to change in it's own element that you can identify.  Then you can use a simple line of jQuery:

```
<div><img src="img1.gif"><br><div id='myText'>My Text</div></div>

$('#myText').text('new text');
```

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
.InnerText
```