# Find text string in jQuery and make it bold

Tags: jquery, css, html

What I want to do is use jQuery to find a piece of text within a paragraph and add some CSS to make it bold. I can't seem to figure out why this won't work:

```
$(window).load(function() {
// ADD BOLD ELEMENTS
$('#about_theresidency:contains("cross genre")').css({'font-weight':'bold'});
});
```

The text in "about_theresidency" is dynamically pulled in, hence me executing it after the window has loaded.

Comment: Even if this will work somehow out, it will make the full element bold, but surely not only your two words. CSS can only be applied to tags, not to text

Comment: @Diodeus i'm using JSON to drop the text into the span tag:

`<div class="content">
    <h1>ABOUT US</h1>
    <span id="about_theresidency"></span>`

Comment: I also tried: 

`$('#about_theresidency:contains("cross genre")').wrap("<b></b>");`

But to no avail

Comment: even being able to add a class to the text would be suitable, just can't figure out how to select that bit of text.

Comment: <span id="about_theresidency"></span> does not contain "cross genre" so the selector will fail.

Comment: well, not in my original html, but it is then populated with the following text http://pastie.org/3637586 ... I should have said that before, sorry!

Comment: If this code is in $(window).load(), where is the code that pulls in the json string and sets the contents? I'm guessing afterwards, which is why this isn't working. $(window).load() is pretty early.

Comment: the other code is in $(document).ready() but when working code (by @elclanrs) isn't running automatically. I'm going to have to get this code to fire at the very end.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can use `replace()` with `html()`:

```
var html = $('p').html();
$('p').html(html.replace(/world/gi, '<strong>$&</strong>'));
```

**Edit:** http://jsbin.com/AvUcElo/1/edit

I turned it into a lil' plugin, here:

```
$.fn.wrapInTag = function(opts) {

  var tag = opts.tag || 'strong'
    , words = opts.words || []
    , regex = RegExp(words.join('|'), 'gi') // case insensitive
    , replacement = '<'+ tag +'>$&</'+ tag +'>';

  return this.html(function() {
    return $(this).text().replace(regex, replacement);
  });
};

// Usage
$('p').wrapInTag({
  tag: 'em',
  words: ['world', 'red']
});
```

Comment: thanks amigo, thats done the trick, stuck it in my loop and it worked!

Comment: nice plugin..but what if there are 1000 of different words which are enclosed withing quotes and all those words needs to be given class red ? we might need to add regex expression in
'code' words: [Regex here, 'red']

what wud be the regex ?

Comment: I guess you can just pass the words with quotes: `words: ['"world"', '"red"']`

Comment: Your solution works, but breaks inner tags (if there were any inside the element you alter), so I took the liberty to modify it a bit and post it as an alternative answer.

Comment: Just as a headsup for anyone else wondering, this fails in IE8 and halts execution.

Answer (score 16):

I had a similar problem and tried to use the solution proposed by elclanrs. It works great, but only if you have no html elements within the text you want to alter. If there were any tags inside the text, they would have been lost after running the `wrapInTag` function.

Here is my inner-node-friendly solution to the problem (I included links to the resources I used to write the code).

```
// http://stackoverflow.com/a/9795091
$.fn.wrapInTag = function (opts) {
    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/1646618
    function getText(obj) {
        return obj.textContent ? obj.textContent : obj.innerText;
    }

    var tag = opts.tag || 'strong',
        words = opts.words || [],
        regex = RegExp(words.join('|'), 'gi'),
        replacement = '<' + tag + '>$&</' + tag + '>';

    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/298758
    $(this).contents().each(function () {
        if (this.nodeType === 3) //Node.TEXT_NODE
        {
            // http://stackoverflow.com/a/7698745
            $(this).replaceWith(getText(this).replace(regex, replacement));
        }
        else if (!opts.ignoreChildNodes) {
            $(this).wrapInTag(opts);
        }
    });
};
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/hawog/1/edit

Comment: Instead of checking for `this.nodeType === 3` you should check `this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE`

Comment: @JasonAxelson As mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/298758, `this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE` will not work in IE7, but `this.nodeType === 3` will work in most browsers.

Comment: Thank you! This is awesome. I found that this matches partial words - so if you pass in 'word' it will match on 'word' and 'sword.' I updated this line of code for the RegExp:

`regex = RegExp('(^|\\s)' + words.join('(\\s|$)|(^|\\s)') + '(\\s|$)', 'gi'),`

This will match on whole words bounded by whitespace only. In my case, I am building a spellchecker, so I needed whole-word highlighting only.

Comment: @Sean I needed this to highlight search results, so matching partial words was intended.

Comment: Both are valid use cases, I think :)

Comment: Why does this not work with a span? Instead of the tag variable I used **replacement = '<span class="red">$&</span>';** and it just does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(window).load(function() {
// ADD BOLD ELEMENTS
    $('#about_theresidency:contains("cross genre")').each(function(){
        $(this).html( 
            $(this).html().replace(/cross genre/g,'<strong>$&</strong>')
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: managed to get it with @elclanrs code, cheers for the input anyway dude!

Answer (score 0):

Needed a more secure method, that could escape. Here is a vanilla solution

```js
var str = 'The world is big <b onclick="alert(false)">world</b> red. the world is also small'
var words = ['world', 'is']
var reg = RegExp(words.join('|'), 'gi')
var p = document.createElement('p')
p.innerText = str
p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.replace(reg, '<u>$&</u>')

document.body.appendChild(p)
console.log(p.outerHTML)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've taken and adjusted @jahu's provided code into a form where you can add data attributes and then run a callback on the dom to then invoke their `$('foo').wrapInTag(...)` in and to allow code like this to exist in your template:

```
<p data-js-highlight-text="hello,">
  <span style="color: #009fff">Hello,</span> World
</p>

// Extended examples with data attributes in your html:
//
// Set the data-js-highlight-text attribute. Before:

<p data-js-highlight-text="hello,">Hello, World</p>

// After:
<p data-js-highlight-text="hello,"><span style="color: #009fff">Hello,</span> World</p>
```