# Applying CSS to words/letters in html document using jQuery or PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find text string in jQuery and make it bold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794851/find-text-string-in-jquery-and-make-it-bold)

Suppose if i have a html document as this

```
<div>
hi this is one line<br>
<p>This is second line</p>
<p>This 'word' is within quote</p>
<p>Another 'lorem ipsum' in quote</p>
</div>
```

How do i apply different CSS only to the word 'line' which occurs many times in my document and also different CSS to all words that appear inside quotes using jQuery. some kind of pattern matching and applying css

any script available to do so ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use JQuery [contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector like this code :

http://jsfiddle.net/z4ZwF/

```
function replaceText(textToSearch,classToApply)
{
  $('div').html($('div').html().replace(new RegExp(textToSearch, 'g'),"<span class='"+classToApply+"'>"+textToSearch+"</span>"));
}
```

Example : `replaceText("'lorem ipsum'",'red')` or `replaceText("line",'red')`

**EDIT**

Add quote wrapping in search and replace : http://jsfiddle.net/z4ZwF/3/

```
function replaceText(textToSearch,classToApply,searchAndWrapQuote)
{
    searchAndWrapQuote = searchAndWrapQuote || false;
    quote = (searchAndWrapQuote) ? "'" : "";

  $('div').html($('div').html().replace(new RegExp(quote+textToSearch+quote, 'g'),"<span class='"+classToApply+"'>"+quote+textToSearch+quote+"</span>"));
}

replaceText("lorem ipsum",'red',true)
```

Comment: Added fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/z4ZwF/

Comment: but what if i have to apply css to all words including quotes that are enclosed within quotes ?

Comment: Enclose the text by quotes like replaceText("'lorem ipsum'",'red') http://jsfiddle.net/z4ZwF/2/

Comment: i mean any word by default which is enclosed withing quotes..we shudnt hard-code the value between quotes..

Comment: btw i liked ur code..its short and simple :)

Comment: I have added an example : http://jsfiddle.net/z4ZwF/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply any style directly to 'line' word. What you need is to parse the content and wrap your 'line' to some tag - for example  and after that you can apply some styles in your css to this class.
You can do this in php as well as in javascript.