# Highlight matching text in javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Highlight text range using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240139/highlight-text-range-using-javascript)
>   [Find text string in jQuery and make it bold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794851/find-text-string-in-jquery-and-make-it-bold)

Supposing I have a bunch of file paths, similar to:

- /Volumes/A//Array/05_SCRIPTS/staging/tree/04_OUTPUTS/MPEG_FF_PS_wCropping/01_NBC_Youtube/Backlog/Archive/LawAndOrder_S20
- /Volumes/A//AArray/05_SCRIPTS/staging/tree/04_OUTPUTS/MPEG_FF_PS_wCropping/01_NBC_Youtube/Backlog/Archive/LawAndOrder_S20/nbcnetwork-pds-E8818-US-insert-20121020

How would I highlight all matches of specific text on the page. For example, if `"04"` was what I was looking for, it would do something like:

```
$(source).find('04').addClass('highlight');
```

This is pseudocode that is probably way off the mark, but this is what I'm looking to do.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794851/find-text-string-in-jquery-and-make-it-bold/9795091#9795091

Answer (score 15, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Aku4y/

```
var t = $(source).html();
t = t.replace(/04/g, "<span class='highlight'>04</span>");
$(source).html(t);
```

Comment: This answer only works for this case; for a better solution you should use `t = t.replace(/04/g, "<span class='highlight'>$&</span>");` instead. This way it works for any text.