# jQuery globally replace string, but not in the Title or Alt attributes

Tags: jquery, string, replace, html

I've written some jQuery that loops through all elements within a div and replaces and styles a specific string by just using <em> and <strong> tags, which works fine and the code is this:

```
var regex = /some text/gi;
$(".container *").each(function () {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(regex, '<em><strong>Some</strong> Text</em>'));
});
```

The problem I have is that this also affects the text in all the Title and Alt attributes, which I don't want because they can't be styled and literally end up being displayed as <em><strong>Some</strong> Text</em>.

I've tried storing the original Title/Alt values in variables before they're replaced then setting them back to their original values afterwards, but it seems that when the attribute values include the <em> and <strong> tags they are completely inaccessible.  I can't even remove them and add them back in, which seems really strange.

Can anyone tell me if there is any way around this please?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $(this).html().replace, have you tried $(this).text().replace?

This way you only replace the actual text of the elements rather than all of the html.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that, but it basically destroys everything so I'm left with an entire page of just plain text.

Comment: Ah sorry about that - this answer should do the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/fw6Pk/

Comment: And here's the original post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794851/find-text-string-in-jquery-and-make-it-bold

Comment: Thanks for that, although I'm still unable to target every single element at once without it including the <em> and <strong> tags.  It works fine if I just target one specific element i.e. <a>, <p>, <div> etc, but when I try to target all of them by using something like ".container *" the direct child elements are replaced OK, but sub children get messed up.  The same thing happens when using my original method.  Do you know if there's a way to target everything including sub children or will I just have to do each one separately?