# jQuery fuzzy search with bold

Tags: javascript, jquery, fuzzy-search

I'm looking for some plugin/script that search some string and bold matching part (fuzzy search)

Below parent > key > result example.

"Hello world" => "hel" => `Hel`lo world

"Hello world" => "hewd" => `He`llo `w`orl`d`

I've found [this](https://github.com/joshaven/string_score) - it has fuzzy option but its not able to bold matching part or parts of string.

Do you know any plugin like this.

Comment: This should help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794851/find-text-string-in-jquery-and-make-it-bold/9795091#9795091

Answer (score 0):

A simple example:

```
$('element').html(function() {
  return $(this).text().replace(/[hewd]/gi, '<strong>$&</strong>');
});
```

Then you can abstract it by building a dynamic regex. The above will match any `h,e,w,d` letter, if you want to match a whole word, you can use word boundaries `\b`:

```
/\bhello\b|[ewd]/ //=> Will match "hello" and all "e,w,d" letters
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/OKUjAtO/3/edit