# RegExp javascript match any word

Tags: javascript, regex, match

Hey all i have found the following code that finds a word within the page:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z7fjW/134/) & [Original Page](http://teeohhem.com/2011/02/20/search-for-and-highlight-text-on-a-page-with-jquery/)

```
function searchAndHighlight(searchTerm, selector) {
    if(searchTerm) {
        //var wholeWordOnly = new RegExp("\\g"+searchTerm+"\\g","ig"); //matches whole word only
        //var anyCharacter = new RegExp("\\g["+searchTerm+"]\\g","ig"); //matches any word with any of search chars characters
        var selector = selector || "body";                             //use body as selector if none provided
        var searchTermRegEx = new RegExp(searchTerm,"ig");
        var matches = $(selector).text().match(searchTermRegEx);
        if(matches) {
            $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');     //Remove old search highlights
                $(selector).html($(selector).html()
                    .replace(searchTermRegEx, "<span class='highlighted'>"+searchTerm+"</span>"));
            if($('.highlighted:first').length) {             //if match found, scroll to where the first one appears
                $(window).scrollTop($('.highlighted:first').position().top);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search-button').on("click",function() {
        if(!searchAndHighlight($('#search-term').val())) {
            alert("No results found");
        }
    });
});
```

Within the code you can see it has **var anyCharacter = new RegExp("\g["+searchTerm+"]\g","ig"); //matches any word with any of search chars characters**.

However, when i try using that RegExp like so:

```
var searchTermRegEx = new RegExp("\\g["+searchTerm+"]\\g","ig");
```

it doesnt seem to return *any* results then even if i type in an exact name.

Any help would be great!

Comment: This might help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794851/find-text-string-in-jquery-and-make-it-bold/9795091#9795091

Answer (score 1):

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wmca4/1/) works.

Not sure what the original authors were thinking with the \\g stuff.

The key is this regex:

```
      searchRegex   = new RegExp('(\\b)(' + searchTerm + ')(\\b)','ig');
```

Comment: Not sure your fiddle works? If you type in **ace** it says it can not find it.. even though *space* has *ace* in it.

Comment: Maybe im looking at this the wrong way.. I am looking for a type of **wildcard** like you would find in a SQL Query **%whateverHere%**.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood.  That solution only finds whole words.  Gimme a sec to match partials....  See http://jsfiddle.net/wmca4/5/

Comment: i have also noticed that if you searched once and then try searching again it does nothing?

Comment: Yes, the fiddle is limited to a single search.  I am quite sure it is the same with the original fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

To match any word, try

```
/^\b\w+\b$/i
```

The regexp matches multiple characters between word boundaries

Replace

```
var searchTermRegEx = new RegExp("\\g["+searchTerm+"]\\g","ig");
```

with

```
var searchTermRegEx = /^\b\w+\b$/i;
```

The difference is that we are using regex literal than using regex object.

Comment: Start and end characters plus global flag doesn't make much sense here.

Comment: Had a confusion whether or not to include it. Fixed.

Comment: @aliasm2k Where would that go in the code in my OP? Can you use that with the code example?