# Find specific word from paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I am finding a specific word from a paragraph and want to make it bold. I have done below code but it's not working.

```js
var text = /Lorem/ig;
$('div')
  .filter(function() {
    return text.test($(this).text())
  }).wrap('<strong></strong>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hH8EV/)

Comment: you don't have .test() method into your JSFIddle code.

Comment: can anyone give me idea why my code is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is **[lil' plugin created by elclanrs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9795091/1719752)**

```
$.fn.wrapInTag = function(opts) {

   var tag = opts.tag || 'strong'
, words = opts.words || []
, regex = RegExp(words.join('|'), 'gi') // case insensitive
, replacement = '<'+ tag +'>Lorem</'+ tag +'>';

 return this.html(function() {
   return $(this).text().replace(regex, replacement);
  });};

// Usage
$('div').wrapInTag({
  tag: 'strong',
  words: ['Lorem']   //can be comma seprated like  ['Lorem','ipsum']
});
```

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hH8EV/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: I think you are linking the wrong fiddle in your working demo.

Comment: how can use for multipal words...I think by this all word will replace with 'Lorem' as per code.

Comment: well then this wont work if you are looking for replacement word to word. need to modify the plugin.

Comment: pls remove this comment //can be comma seprated like  ['Lorem','ipsum'].

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex backreference:

```
var text=new RegExp('(Lorem)','ig');
$('div').html($('div').html().replace(text, "<strong>$1</strong>"));
```