# Replace character javascript / php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, find, character

I have a problem with a Google Font. I implemented a Google Font into my website. Now the thing is, that the "&" sign looks really strange. So I'd like to use a different font only for the "&" character. I think something like this should work:

```
<p>hello <span class="otherfont">&</span> good bye</p>
```

No I wanted to search the page for the "&" and wrap it with the span. My first thought was `$('#main-content').find('&').wrap('<span></span>');`. But of course this woun't work..

Does anybody have an idea? If not in JS/Jquery maybe in php?
Thanks!

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794851/find-text-string-in-jquery-and-make-it-bold/9795091#9795091

Answer (score 0):

```
var mainContent = $('#mainContent').text();
var newContent = mainContent.replace(/&/g, '<span class="otherfont">&</span>');
$('#mainContent').html(newContent);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w4DhR/1/

UPDATE:
    To make use of `html()` in stead of `text();` rewrite the `&` symbol to `&amp;`

```
var newContent = mainContent.replace(/&amp;/g, '<span class="otherfont">&amp;</span>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w4DhR/3/

Comment: Thanks! I had to change one thing. It deleted all my html. It works like this `var mainContent = $('#main-content').html();`
But now it add a `amp;` right after the new span. Do you know why?

Comment: Most `amp;` is HTML for the & synbol. So it probably has some issues with the fact that I look for & using the exact symbol. I'll try and update the code.

Comment: @NicoHöckel Change the selector to `var newContent = mainContent.replace(/&amp;/g, '<span class="otherfont">&amp;</span>');`
I'll update the code

Comment: Now another problem appeared. It does change all the `&` but all the other JS doesn't work anymore. Any guess?

Comment: I have no idea what your other JS consists of, nor what error it returns. So no, no guess =).

Comment: Thats the problem. There are no warnings or errors. I'm working with jquery lazyload those events are of course after the document.ready. Without your script the `<noscript>` looks like this `<img src="pic.jpg" alt="" width="260" height="300" />` afterwards there are all `<`replaced with `&lt;`